# Passing JSONArray to PHP from Android

Tags: php, android, json, arrays

I have read through many other questions regarding PHP and JSONArray looping. I am sending in a JSONArray of values of different students with their class and studentId from my Android device. Using these values, I search the database for their names and return a JSONArray.

```
JSON Input: [{"studentId":"2","class":"2a","dbname":"testDb"}]
<?php

 $jsonString = $_POST['json'];  //see comment below

 $jArray = json_decode($jsonString, true);

 $conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pwd' );

mysql_select_db('dbname', $conn);

foreach( $jArray as $obj ){
    $className = $obj['class'];   //String
    $id= $obj['studentId'];       //int

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM student WHERE class='$className' AND id='$id'");

    $e=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);    //will only fetch 1 row of result
    $output[]=$e;


}

      echo (json_encode($output));

?>
```

Android

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response;
try{
 HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://abc/getName.php");
 List<NameValuePair> nVP = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);  
 nVP.add(new BasicNameValuePair("json", studentJson.toString()));  //studentJson is the JSON input

//student.Json.toString() produces the correct JSON [{"studentId":"2","class":"2a","dbname":"testDb"}]

 post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nVP));
 response = client.execute(post);
if(response!=null){
//process data send from php
}  
}
```

**SOLVED:** See answer below

Comment: Update your post with your *JSONArray* input and the output of `print_r($jArray);`

Comment: I just ran this, but first simplified it. Set `$jsonString = '[{"regNo":"2","class":"2a","dbname":"TestData"}]'` then after `$id= $obj['studentId'];` I did `echo "SELECT name FROM student WHERE class='$className' AND id='$id'"` and it worked. (also, I took out any reference to output or mysql). Try outputting your JSON object (after decoding) to ensure it's an array, and the incoming JSON string is not malformed.

Comment: As @JasonMcCreary said earlier, add the data that you get. Add to the post your `var_dump($jsonString);` and `var_dump($jArray);` output. Maybe $jArray is null or so...

Comment: Thanks guys, that was the problem, $jArray is null... the PHP could not retrieve my JSONArray input

Comment: I have edited my question to include the part where I send in the JSONArray input

Comment: Try pointing the http post to an actual server, see if you can get the json.

Comment: yup, i realised where was the error. Take a look at my updated post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**SOLVED:** Finally understood what was the problem. After posting from Android to PHP script, my JSONArray becomes `[{\"studentId\":"2\",\"class\":\"2a\",\"dbname\":\"testDb\"}]` To remove the "\", use PHP command `stripslashes` Spent 4 hours debugging!

Hope this will be a good guide for those that wants to send and retrieve data between Android and PHP

Answer (score 1):

Here's your problem:

```
print_r(json_decode('[{"regNo":"2","class":"2a","dbname":"TestData"}]',true));
```

returns `Array ( [0] => Array ( [regNo] => 2 [class] => 2a [dbname] => TestData ) )` meaning your decoded json is put within an array

Use `array_shift(json_decode($jsonString, true));` to remove the parent array.

Comment: While this is a good point, it doesn't explain the error *Invalid argument for foreach()* as it should still loop the parent array.